# Is this question ok to ask here?

Tags: discussion

*Question*

Is it possible to make an android device "blast" through a call(or what looks like an incoming call) ?

*description*

There is a whatsapp rumor spreading informing that if a call comes to your phone from a specific number then receiving it may make your phone explode.

I know a bit of programming and stuff and it feels kind of unsettling and impossible to make a phone go boom from a software. At most what I can think of is overclocking of CPU to burn it.

Is it possible to make a phone blast through an incoming call ? (or atleast overclock the CPU ?)

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13105/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-computer-into-a-bomb/13144). If you want to know if this specific rumor is true (ass opposed to if this is theoretically possible), [Sceptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) might also work (but read their rules before you post).

Comment: @Anders I think rumors are rumors but what I want is solid stuff that can base the answer to my question, so I think my question should belong here on security.SE

Comment: If you ask here, make sure to do it in a way so that your questions are not answered by the answers to the question I linked.

Comment: @Anders thanks, I will have a close look to the link you shared.

Comment: Mukul - as Anders said, this is really a Skeptics question. Not a security question as far as our scope is concerned.

Comment: an exploding phone poses no information security risk,

Comment: @Jasen: I do not agree with you. A phone can contain data and knowing what can make  that data vanish is a security question (think about the A of the CIA triad). But until it has been proven is *can* happen, the question is just a rumor and is probably more on topic in Skeptics

Comment: fair enough, it's also denial of service,